# How to resize camera resolution android?

Tags: java, android, camera, resize

I want to resize resolution camera to be 100x400 like image below. I try in android sample camerapreview. But i don't know to resize it.

[image: camera]

Comment: Please rephrase your question and add some more details

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the camera preview resolutions the device supports, and then set accordingly:

```
    Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> supportedSizes = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    int maxSupportedWidth = -1;
    int maxSupportedHeight = -1;
    for (Camera.Size size : supportedSizes) {
        if (size.width == 100) {
            desiredWidth = size.width;
            desiredHeight = size.height;
        }
    }

    p.setPictureSize(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
```

There's no guarantee that he device supports the exact resolution of 100x400 or that the height in the above example would equal 400, but you get the idea of how to set it to something close to what you want.